# putting value of one array into a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am very new to python and I have a line of code 
`print docClassifier.predict(temp)` 
which basically prints an array of this format `[0,0,1,1,1,0....]`. Now I want to store this array in a list for some other processing and the output of list should be same as array. I tried doing list.append() but when I print this list using `for item in enumerate(list)` the output is not the same as of array.It is like this `(0,array([0,0,1,1...])`. How can I correct this?

Comment: Show your code where you convert your 'array' to a list please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert numpy arrays to lists, like this

```
my_list = np.array([0,0,1,1,1,0]).tolist()
```

You can check their types to confirm it like this

```
>>> type(np.array([0,0,1,1,1,0]))
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(np.array([0,0,1,1,1,0]).tolist())
<type 'list'>
```

If you want to `enumerate` the list, you can do it like this

```
for index, current_number in enumerate(np.array([0,0,1,1,1,0]).tolist()):
    print index, current_number
```

In fact, if you are just going to iterate, you don't even have to convert that to a list,

```
>>> for index, current_number in enumerate(np.array([0,0,1,1,1,0])):
...     print index, current_number
...     
... 
0 0
1 0
2 1
3 1
4 1
5 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`enumerate` will return you `tuple` with index and value. You can try

```
for index, value in enumerate(list):
    print index
    print value
```